# Word for testing a product on yourself

Tags: single-word-requests

How would I say that I am going to test a product on myself?

For instance "Due to the X testing I will not need to worry about signing ethical forms" (As you might need to sign ethical forms for when testing patients).

Edit (based on a comment by the OP):
it's for an application; if I wanted to get patients to test it I would need to go past an ethics committee to make sure I'm not doing anything bad with their data. But if it's on myself I don't need to go to them.

Comment: You are possibly looking for [*self-experimentation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-experimentation). *Self-testing* might also be usable but it is rather ambiguous.

Comment: @Rathony `"Due to the X testing I will not need to worry about signing ethical forms" `

Comment: @Rathony - I don't see what's difficult to understand. They are talking about a case where a product is tested on the experimenter themself rather than testing on other people. Examples of this are https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn16735-eight-scientists-who-became-their-own-guinea-pigs/ (something the answer does totally ignore)

Comment: @Rathony - It doesn't matter if they are the inventor or not. But clearly from the example sentence they are in some sort of research setting where carrying out experiments on humans would require the subjects to sign consent forms. But because they are carrying the experiment out on themself they believe this requirement is not necessary.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes you are correct. Due to testing on yourself you don't need "permission"

Comment: The way you would phrase this would certainly depend on whether or not the document is for legal purposes. If you are in the US and at an academic institution, or have received government grant money for your research, your human subjects review committee would certainly want to know that you are testing something on yourself, and would have specific language. If this is the case you should refer to their guidelines.

Comment: @jackdh - you don't need permission for what. Are you referring  to something illegal ?

Comment: @JOSH No lol, its for an application, if I wanted to get patients to test it I would need to go past an ethics committee to make sure I'm not doing anything bad with there data. But if it's on myself I don't need to go to them.

Comment: You may still need approval before you undertake experimentation on yourself if you are doing this at an institution. But not if you are doing it at home in your basement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for [*self-experimentation*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-experimentation). It's a little verbose but seems to convey the right meaning.

***Famous last words**: In order not to worry about signing ethical forms, I resorted to self-experimentation.*

Answer (score -1):

You could say you're [eating you own dog food](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/eatyourowndogfood.asp#ixzz4PAB4sGFV).  Though this is traditionally a software term, it is being used more generally nowadays.

> DEFINITION of 'Eat Your Own Dog Food'. 
>   **A colloquialism that describes a company using its own products or services for its internal operations**. The term is believed to have originated with Microsoft in the 1980s. While it was originally used in reference to software companies using their own internally-generated tools for software development, its usage has spread to other areas as well. Often shortened simply to "dog food."
>
> — [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/eatyourowndogfood.asp#ixzz4PAB4sGFV)

Comment: The word "application" in the question is not referring to that type of application.

Comment: @MartinSmith ok I've edited my answer to remove my explicit reference to application. I find the question somewhat unclear to be honest.